Why does lp() linear solver in R find a better solution when given a smaller subset of options?
Given a set of 140 options, my goal is to select the set of options that minimize the objective function and acheive a constraint that weight must be > 5584 units.
Criteria 1 is the objective function to minimize.
The thing I didn't expect and do not understand is why when I reduce the option set to only a smaller subset of options, lp() finds me a more optimal solution.
Note that I do not have a strong math background, so don't understand well the math underlying it. But, I had understood that linear programming would find me the best solution available every time.
Here is a reproducible example:

#First define the FULL option set of 140 options, each with a weight and a criteria 1.  

DFToOptimizeFull <- structure(list(item_ID = c("Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4", 
                           "Option5", "Option6", "Option7", "Option8", "Option9", "Option10", 
                           "Option11", "Option12", "Option13", "Option14", "Option15", "Option16", 
                           "Option17", "Option18", "Option19", "Option20", "Option21", "Option22", 
                           "Option23", "Option24", "Option25", "Option26", "Option27", "Option28", 
                           "Option29", "Option30", "Option31", "Option32", "Option33", "Option34", 
                           "Option35", "Option36", "Option37", "Option38", "Option39", "Option40", 
                           "Option41", "Option42", "Option43", "Option44", "Option45", "Option46", 
                           "Option47", "Option48", "Option49", "Option50", "Option51", "Option52", 
                           "Option53", "Option54", "Option55", "Option56", "Option57", "Option58", 
                           "Option59", "Option60", "Option61", "Option62", "Option63", "Option64", 
                           "Option65", "Option66", "Option67", "Option68", "Option69", "Option70", 
                           "Option71", "Option72", "Option73", "Option74", "Option75", "Option76", 
                           "Option77", "Option78", "Option79", "Option80", "Option81", "Option82", 
                           "Option83", "Option84", "Option85", "Option86", "Option87", "Option88", 
                           "Option89", "Option90", "Option91", "Option92", "Option93", "Option94", 
                           "Option95", "Option96", "Option97", "Option98", "Option99", "Option100", 
                           "Option101", "Option102", "Option103", "Option104", "Option105", 
                           "Option106", "Option107", "Option108", "Option109", "Option110", 
                           "Option111", "Option112", "Option113", "Option114", "Option115", 
                           "Option116", "Option117", "Option118", "Option119"), criteria_1 = c(0.19382357870646, 
                                                                                               0.406093545012686, 0.26444538198799, 0.26601032196915, 0.582727750839455, 
                                                                                               0.610218171520381, 0.278839154130233, 0.121920371729594, 0.394236226297326, 
                                                                                               0.377841864658525, 0.120477145449607, 0.26254096134174, 0.320858353224026, 
                                                                                               0.157895381699022, 0.367337498338429, 0.178897294673147, 0.206447474122835, 
                                                                                               0.125249409058597, 0.0964062671575285, 0.155883926971779, 0.745589005311248, 
                                                                                               0.271814782493108, 1, 0.709925503817279, 0.283967774188142, 0.465574672453751, 
                                                                                               0.747720902276497, 0.261597766848332, 0.223547497818285, 0.312169636303741, 
                                                                                               0.361688040733056, 0.33135717134122, 0.720315669627635, 0.597242543157505, 
                                                                                               0.793399950297349, 0.422337180472638, 0.319528402753296, 0.430606430135989, 
                                                                                               0.397399279889498, 0.343212756243173, 0.330215166243809, 0.266929589837542, 
                                                                                               0.341647931849574, 0.337592426703038, 0.42473989909206, 0.308525738460027, 
                                                                                               0.424706956637327, 0.357390032884661, 0.280438539204411, 0.409378774656271, 
                                                                                               0.346474174849303, 0.791793745557103, 0.450584584087061, 0.262056880638506, 
                                                                                               0.311923434799947, 0.448835397534517, 0.330430390281398, 0.141640071895463, 
                                                                                               0.1929124019673, 0.176881794381289, 0.379488987395177, 0.741791953949916, 
                                                                                               0.0370066289465928, 0.0768869958215097, 0.147257049396344, 0.570100734558947, 
                                                                                               0.36424969224812, 0.254741112761445, 0.339564812834843, 0.305964896057886, 
                                                                                               0.286239647689116, 0.326383438614336, 0.458683804448965, 0.567810482635859, 
                                                                                               0.235202885065509, 0.729063336203758, 0.341599616249299, 0.153703714406256, 
                                                                                               0.117457767195094, 0.134082379254345, 0.558969536898439, 0.286059793445029, 
                                                                                               0.322705673615406, 0.396612822128083, 0.100616428459969, 0.156259239780615, 
                                                                                               0.232564021060054, 0.104164041865814, 0.210723751509863, 0.192397806148102, 
                                                                                               0.166759676123656, 0.310175982060811, 0.200003698801935, 0.193767171976952, 
                                                                                               0.137411647758468, 0.369825867340157, 0.429786451982038, 0.202788665483821, 
                                                                                               0.786777129845286, 0.321634986042802, 0.496148738072809, 0.170282669379121, 
                                                                                               0.140613654358518, 0.155074004935589, 0.106219651041155, 0.121895751579215, 
                                                                                               0.144999508752868, 0.278420842748903, 0.61995781054043, 0.860520490784782, 
                                                                                               0.860520490784782, 0.894125146651717, 0.894125146651717, 0.894125146651717, 
                                                                                               0.443148836322235, 0.120796860641858, 0.0224245646683504, 0.223040877540759, 
                                                                                               0.195655525952297), itemWeight = c(151, 482, 309, 323, 648, 766, 
                                                                                                                                                                     309, 29, 385, 232, 114, 104, 326, 172, 69, 133, 130, 107, 222, 
                                                                                                                                                                     118, 657, 152, 1150, 723, 339, 516, 1126, 300, 247, 372, 286, 
                                                                                                                                                                     380, 935, 849, 1239, 571, 344, 639, 640, 476, 456, 336, 563, 
                                                                                                                                                                     536, 682, 463, 477, 518, 350, 695, 384, 953, 457, 284, 345, 549, 
                                                                                                                                                                     418, 196, 276, 217, 569, 657, 37, 78, 151, 613, 392, 280, 389, 
                                                                                                                                                                     320, 332, 366, 584, 619, 258, 903, 349, 160, 124, 141, 671, 282, 
                                                                                                                                                                     333, 428, 97, 57, 251, 62, 214, 194, 167, 316, 198, 231, 135, 
                                                                                                                                                                     345, 514, 188, 787, 359, 522, 168, 128, 165, 114, 129, 131, 92, 
                                                                                                                                                                     374, 307, 307, 307, 307, 307, 86, 73, 7, 109, 208)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        -119L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


#Minimize criteria 1 on the full set
minimizedC_1FullSet <- lp(direction = "min",
   objective.in = 
     DFToOptimizeFull$criteria_1,
   const.mat = matrix(
     DFToOptimizeFull$itemWeight, nrow = 1), 
   
   const.dir = ">=", #firm energy must be greater than or equal to
   const.rhs = 5584, #the energy target
   all.bin = TRUE)

minimizedC_1FullSet
#I get 3.548285. 

#--
#Now lets solve the exact same problem but on only a select number of options. Not the full set.  


DFToOptimizeSelect <- DFToOptimizeFull %>% filter(item_ID %in% c( "Option19", "Option27", "Option35", 
                                            "Option39", "Option43", "Option45", 
                                            "Option50", "Option57"))


minimizedC_1Select <- lp(direction = "min",
                             objective.in = 
                           DFToOptimizeSelect$criteria_1,
                             const.mat = matrix(
                               DFToOptimizeSelect$itemWeight, nrow = 1), 
                             
                             const.dir = ">=", #firm energy must be greater than or equal to
                             const.rhs = 5584, #the energy target
                             all.bin = TRUE)


minimizedC_1Select
#I get 3.541123, which is 0.007162 less than I got on the full set. 

This may seem like splitting hairs, but it causes me to lose confidence that lp() is finding me the optimal solution.
Please help me understand why this is possible??? This optimization is a key analysis in my post-doc, and I need to be confident the optimization is working properly. Could it be a bug in the lp() function?

Did you mean to write "minimizing criteria 1 would minimize criteria 1"? If you found a better solution, please describe it.

You haven't referenced criteria_2 anywhere in your problem. So how can you claim that you attempted to minimize it?

Thanks for your reply. I beleive criteria 2 is not relevant for making a simple reproducible example, so I have removed it. It takes quite a lot of extra code to minimize criteria 2 and demonstrate that it provides a lower criteria 1. But, if you think it would be helpful or necessary, I could add that full set of code.

Given
import pandas as pd
import pulp

item_ID = pd.RangeIndex(name='item_ID', start=1, stop=120)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=item_ID,
    data={
        'criteria_1': (
            0.19382357870646,
            0.406093545012686, 0.26444538198799, 0.26601032196915, 0.582727750839455,
            0.610218171520381, 0.278839154130233, 0.121920371729594, 0.394236226297326,
            0.377841864658525, 0.120477145449607, 0.26254096134174, 0.320858353224026,
            0.157895381699022, 0.367337498338429, 0.178897294673147, 0.206447474122835,
            0.125249409058597, 0.0964062671575285, 0.155883926971779, 0.745589005311248,
            0.271814782493108, 1, 0.709925503817279, 0.283967774188142, 0.465574672453751,
            0.747720902276497, 0.261597766848332, 0.223547497818285, 0.312169636303741,
            0.361688040733056, 0.33135717134122, 0.720315669627635, 0.597242543157505,
            0.793399950297349, 0.422337180472638, 0.319528402753296, 0.430606430135989,
            0.397399279889498, 0.343212756243173, 0.330215166243809, 0.266929589837542,
            0.341647931849574, 0.337592426703038, 0.42473989909206, 0.308525738460027,
            0.424706956637327, 0.357390032884661, 0.280438539204411, 0.409378774656271,
            0.346474174849303, 0.791793745557103, 0.450584584087061, 0.262056880638506,
            0.311923434799947, 0.448835397534517, 0.330430390281398, 0.141640071895463,
            0.1929124019673, 0.176881794381289, 0.379488987395177, 0.741791953949916,
            0.0370066289465928, 0.0768869958215097, 0.147257049396344, 0.570100734558947,
            0.36424969224812, 0.254741112761445, 0.339564812834843, 0.305964896057886,
            0.286239647689116, 0.326383438614336, 0.458683804448965, 0.567810482635859,
            0.235202885065509, 0.729063336203758, 0.341599616249299, 0.153703714406256,
            0.117457767195094, 0.134082379254345, 0.558969536898439, 0.286059793445029,
            0.322705673615406, 0.396612822128083, 0.100616428459969, 0.156259239780615,
            0.232564021060054, 0.104164041865814, 0.210723751509863, 0.192397806148102,
            0.166759676123656, 0.310175982060811, 0.200003698801935, 0.193767171976952,
            0.137411647758468, 0.369825867340157, 0.429786451982038, 0.202788665483821,
            0.786777129845286, 0.321634986042802, 0.496148738072809, 0.170282669379121,
            0.140613654358518, 0.155074004935589, 0.106219651041155, 0.121895751579215,
            0.144999508752868, 0.278420842748903, 0.61995781054043, 0.860520490784782,
            0.860520490784782, 0.894125146651717, 0.894125146651717, 0.894125146651717,
            0.443148836322235, 0.120796860641858, 0.0224245646683504, 0.223040877540759,
            0.195655525952297,
        ),
        'criteria_2': (
            0.17641981214023, 0.240848545191324,
            0.20835265524648, 0.248767529787931, 0.451793498520131, 0.381683037411269,
            0.241976585373557, 0.116782623551492, 0.20673566370936, 0.286801382192965,
            0.070652688912388, 0.364572800178567, 0.269242816166067, 0.1189751136006,
            0.323905107166701, 0.193872198256378, 0.147740819150117, 0.0860132098261335,
            0.0580418616854518, 0.109446297259946, 0.500647366537576, 0.180393459509617,
            0.653491503844082, 0.472660220201084, 0.163162249237616, 0.283984633127125,
            0.415992733266123, 0.164994074648886, 0.167340730610985, 0.268800486663044,
            0.32576183372859, 0.187746554917954, 0.513868883897277, 0.407993976147579,
            0.520823834574429, 0.346647590611749, 0.249144414555891, 0.36143709685635,
            0.275195240878429, 0.210744193768878, 0.276940989909035, 0.213850998663282,
            0.189043772333223, 0.256031575641972, 0.267888778202805, 0.299825443704003,
            0.232862594751094, 0.293319667536792, 0.165555116687722, 0.249950801232123,
            0.185427153206608, 0.450646068867545, 0.283324056730209, 0.215590084378473,
            0.168950797268736, 0.305193207638845, 0.190241720123152, 0.168636009700241,
            0.140235480483511, 0.116295393379208, 0.254990237458096, 0.534546957175079,
            0.0342844548026959, 0.147617877226165, 0.0856553598188811, 0.360464565082389,
            0.26523128883826, 0.157202592030299, 0.189919356942208, 0.16741285463652,
            0.184588573334462, 0.194498543981115, 0.290262033461934, 0.376277472517838,
            0.167260290450748, 0.494939091832352, 0.312304468360028, 0.125687206435128,
            0.124559809278627, 0.10118904396013, 0.436260473197599, 0.268812179666543,
            0.28390152035242, 0.319129746519373, 0.0887131242082749, 0.0936087834963992,
            0.146028350082448, 0.0852325359256434, 0.141593369478712, 0.142175267274303,
            0.119637448691408, 0.213864087532372, 0.143729711242536, 0.240836706142566,
            0.0857609795196696, 0.284704814576988, 0.321668930739399, 0.178845649197193,
            0.893388564922643, 0.22274883820528, 0.43912198342029, 0.174430954851812,
            0.118927528091718, 0.100615369508259, 0.0691456056815229, 0.0878417595367306,
            0.133033845100036, 0.262412843717465, 0.320020039396849, 0.440301379519025,
            0.440301379519025, 0.705078014946413, 0.705078014946413, 0.705078014946413,
            0.478037536193209, 0.0604065918539912, 0.0112204438672376, 0.117238408833876,
            0.131639362146937,
        ),
        'itemWeight': (
            151, 482, 309, 323, 648, 766,
            309, 29, 385, 232, 114, 104, 326, 172, 69, 133, 130, 107, 222,
            118, 657, 152, 1150, 723, 339, 516, 1126, 300, 247, 372, 286,
            380, 935, 849, 1239, 571, 344, 639, 640, 476, 456, 336, 563,
            536, 682, 463, 477, 518, 350, 695, 384, 953, 457, 284, 345, 549,
            418, 196, 276, 217, 569, 657, 37, 78, 151, 613, 392, 280, 389,
            320, 332, 366, 584, 619, 258, 903, 349, 160, 124, 141, 671, 282,
            333, 428, 97, 57, 251, 62, 214, 194, 167, 316, 198, 231, 135,
            345, 514, 188, 787, 359, 522, 168, 128, 165, 114, 129, 131, 92,
            374, 307, 307, 307, 307, 307, 86, 73, 7, 109, 208,
        ),
        'select': pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
            name='select', indices=item_ID, cat=pulp.LpBinary,
        ),
    },
)

prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='backpack', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)

firm_energy = pulp.lpDot(df['itemWeight'], df['select'])
prob.addConstraint(
    name='min_firm_energy', constraint=firm_energy >= 5584,
)

the first solution is
# Minimize criteria 1 on the full set
prob.setObjective(pulp.lpDot(df['criteria_1'], df['select']))

prob.solve()
assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal
firm_energy = firm_energy.value()
df['select'] = df['select'].apply(pulp.value)
df = df.loc[df['select'] > 0.5, ['criteria_1', 'criteria_2', 'itemWeight']]
print(df)

Objective value:                3.48857926
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               42
Time (CPU seconds):             0.03
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.03

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.03   (Wallclock seconds):       0.03

         criteria_1  criteria_2  itemWeight
item_ID                                    
19         0.096406    0.058042         222
35         0.793400    0.520824        1239
39         0.397399    0.275195         640
43         0.341648    0.189044         563
44         0.337592    0.256032         536
45         0.424740    0.267889         682
46         0.308526    0.299825         463
50         0.409379    0.249951         695
61         0.379489    0.254990         569

and the second solution is
Objective value:                2.16717874
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               0
Time (CPU seconds):             0.01
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.01

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.02   (Wallclock seconds):       0.02

         criteria_1  criteria_2  itemWeight
item_ID                                    
19         0.096406    0.058042         222
27         0.747721    0.415993        1126
35         0.793400    0.520824        1239
39         0.397399    0.275195         640
43         0.341648    0.189044         563
45         0.424740    0.267889         682
50         0.409379    0.249951         695
57         0.330430    0.190242         418

It's fully expected that the two solutions be different given different objectives.

I appreciate your response Reinderien, but have edited the question to more clearly highlight my problem: I get a better solution given a more limited subset of options given the exact same objectives. Also, an answer in R would be needed to answer the question.
